# No resource.labels.function_name after migrate to cloud functions gen2

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm migrating a Firebase Cloud Function from gen1 to gen2.
In gen1, the logger had `resource.labels.function_name`, so I was able to filter by function in the Log Explorer. But in the new function, using the same set of options to create it, the `resource.labels` field in the Log Explorer is different. I was expecting internal changes in the function behavior, but not in the logger.

- Do you know how to filter per function name?
- Is there a place with the differences between gen1 and gen2 in relation to the logger?

This is the options used to create the functions:

```js
import {CallableOptions, onCall} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import * as logger from "firebase-functions/logger";

const options: CallableOptions = {
  labels: {
    group: "user_profile"
  },
  timeoutSeconds: 2,
  memory: "128MiB",
  minInstances: 0,
  maxInstances: 2,
  // enforceAppCheck: true,
};

onCall(options, async (req) => {
 logger.info("Example of logger");
}
```